# display node inside colorbox

Tags: 6, javascript

Is it possible to display a node content (without sidebar etc.) inside colorbox in Drupal 6.
I know there is module for that in drupal 7 - colorbox-node. But I could not find any thread bout same functionality for drupal 6. Can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup) module. There is a version for Drupal 6.

> The popup suite allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes, blocks, menus, forms, views and php-generated content.